# Apache POI : Formula gets removed while reading the cell value using formula FormulaEvaluator

Tags: excel, apache-poi, xssf, poi-hssf

I am using poi version 3.17. In my java code I want to read a cell value which has formula and I am using `evaluateInCell` function of `FormulaEvaluator` to resolve the cell value.

I have a template excel in my resource in which cells has formulas, if I create a workbook from this and set some value, and try to read it back, the `FormulaEvaluator` resolve the cell and put the actual value, by this formula of those cells get replaced and updated with actual value. WHY??

I have seen the implementation of `evaluateInCell` function which intentionally setting the cell type as `setCellType(cell, cv);`

```
public XSSFCell evaluateInCell(Cell cell) {
        if (cell == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            XSSFCell result = (XSSFCell)cell;
            if (cell.getCellType() == 2) {
                CellValue cv = this.evaluateFormulaCellValue(cell);
                setCellType(cell, cv);
                setCellValue(cell, cv);
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Why library is doing so, and removing actual formula from the cell.

Comment: What you observe is exactly what also is mentioned in [FormulaEvaluator.evaluateInCell](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/FormulaEvaluator.html#evaluateInCell-org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell-). "Be aware that your cell value will be changed to hold the result of the formula. If you simply want the formula value computed for you, use [evaluateFormulaCell(Cell)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/FormulaEvaluator.html#evaluateFormulaCell-org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell-)". So why not doing exactly this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different functions:

```
 CellType evaluateFormulaCell(Cell cell) - your cell will hold both the formula, and the result.       
 Cell evaluateInCell(Cell cell) - you cell will contain result only, formula is erased.      
 CellValue evaluate(Cell cell) - the formula is evaluated and returned. No changes in the cell.    
 void evaluateAll() = mass evaluateFormulaCell for the whole book.
```

Obviously, you have taken `evaluateInCell` for `evaluateFormulaCell`. `evaluateInCell` is very useful, and not only for counting - Use it for clean erasing of formulae.

Also, don't forget `clearAllCachedResultValues()` or `notifyUpdateCell()`/`notifySetFormula()`. Without those, any evaluation after any changes on the sheet can fail.